# Cannot import mp3/wav files in React with file-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mp3, loader

I've been trying to import some mp3 and wav files in React, but I'm getting errors on compiling which seem related to loaders.

Different syntax.

```
      {
        test: /\.(mp3|wav)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },

Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

import sad from './sad.mp3';

this.wrongSound = new Audio(sad);
```

This doesn't seem to work. However, this does without loaders at all:

```
this.wrongSound = new Audio('./src/sad.mp3');
```

I want to know why this is.